# Is CSS used anywhere besides web browsers?

Tags: css

Just curious - apart from its ubiquitous use in specifying the presentation of HTML in modern web browsers, do any programs or standards utilize CSS?

Comment: Could you please expand on your question?  I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: You can always make an interpreter or parser for your own needs :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mozilla uses CSS to style the user interface of its products (Firefox, Thunderbird, Sunbird, etc.). It also uses CSS to bind logic to markup (`-moz-binding`).

Flex is also using [custom CSS properties](http://www.digitalchickenscratch.com/misc/flex-css/) to style the interface.

Furthermore, the [Qt GUI framework (written in C++) is using CSS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS,HTML and jQuery in **Adobe Air** framework to create cross platform Desktop applications also. Please check [this](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/css-desktop-adobe-air) article.

[Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) is platform for building rich desktop applications. It also uses existing web technologies including css to do that. [Here](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/titanium/) is more information about it.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets), you can apply CSS to any markup language, XML, XUL, SVG etc.

Comment: It can, but it rarely is. (I'd say never, but I'm not too sure)

Comment: And where exactly would you see the effects of applying that CSS?

Comment: Ken, in XUL's case you can see it when using Firefox. Firefox is built using XUL. I don't know for the others though.

Answer (score 2):

http://adium.im/

The Adium chat client can be skinned using CSS and I'm pretty confident this is not the only application going that way.

Now, this is not CSS in the strict sense of the way since, as pointed by previous posters, CSS was specifically designed and standardized for typically browser rendered documents (XML, XUL, SVG for instance).

Answer (score 2):

Prince XML, a tool for generating PDFs, uses CSS. It even passes Acid2 test.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by web browsers. There are print style sheets used by web browsers to output something that's printed. CSS is used for the paper by the browser, but it's still used on the printed document.

All the recognized media types:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in [HTML e-mail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_e-mail). E-mail clients that support HTML e-mails under a renderer to display the HTML document with CSS styles applied.

Mozilla Thunderbird uses Gecko as the rendering engine (the one used in Firefox), whereas Microsoft Outlook 2007 uses its inbuilt rendering engine (different from the Trident rendering engine used in Microsoft IE).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the CSS syntax popup as a selection tool more than a styling tool recently.  The most widely used example of this is jQuery's use of CSS selectors.

Comment: Indeed, and can be used on non-HTML documents as well!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's used in XUL, the system that Firefox and other Mozilla applications are built with. The XULRunner allows other developers to build [XUL based applications; see this list on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XULRunner).

Answer (score 0):

Many Linux applications use an embedded HTML-rendering widget to display some text.  For example [Kopete](http://kopete.kde.org), an instant messenger program, uses HTML and CSS to render skins.  HTML+CSS is a cheap way to render rich text.

Answer (score 0):

There are some GTK (Graphical Toolkit) style properties that are controlled with "css like" style files.
This is one example of a project that tries to use actual CSS for the GTK styling:
http://blogs.gnome.org/theming/2008/10/01/announce-gtk-css-engine-02-available/

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in Flash to style your user interface elements. That actually quite useful, as changes to your website's style are directly visible in Flash.